# Addresses versus unique addresses

Tags: address, network, volume

So, according to blockchain.info there are roughly 942,000 unique addresses as of a few days ago.  When I go to the Bitcoin Rich List on www.bitinfocharts.com it looks like there are 23+ million addresses.

Can someone explain the difference?  What is a unique address?  How does is differ from the 23 mm addresses?

Thanks.